# SQL-запрос на выборку из 2-х таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE movie (
 movieId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 description VARCHAR(255) NULL,
 active BOOLEAN,
 PRIMARY KEY (movieId)
);
CREATE TABLE seance (
 seanceid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 date DATE NOT NULL,
 cost INT NOT NULL,
 sold INT NOT NULL,
 active BOOLEAN,
 movieId INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (seanceId)
);
```

Первая таблица хранит только фильмы. Во второй сеансы (много сеансов для каждого фильма), cost - стоимость билета, sold - кол-во билетов проданных на сеанс. Movie.active - показывают или снят с проката. Seance.active - отменен или нет.

Необходимо сделать выборку: movieId, m.name, m.active, сумму заработанных денег каждым фильмом, на всех сеансах (не учитывать деньги с отмененных сеансов), будут ли показы с участием данного фильма сегодня и в будущем.

Вот что у меня получается на данный момент:

```
SELECT 
m.movieId, 
m.name, 
m.active, 
IFNULL(SUM(s.sold*s.cost), 0) AS earned, 
EXISTS(SELECT s.date >= getDate()) as work 
FROM movie AS m 
LEFT JOIN seance AS s 
ON (m.movieId = s.movieId) 
WHERE s.active
GROUP BY m.movieId
```

Но вот с work не выходит совладать. Помогите сделать выборку и укажите на ошибки. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inner join для поиска сумм и left join для проверки дат в будущем:

```
insert into movie(name, active) values
("foo", true),
("bar",true);

insert into seance(date,cost,sold,active,movieId) values
("2018-04-18",100,5,true,1),
("2018-04-19",10,2,true,1),
("2018-04-20",25,3,false,1),
("2018-04-18",101,5,false,2),
("2018-04-19",11,2,false,2),
("2018-04-20",26,3,false,2);

SELECT
    m.movieId, 
    m.name, 
    m.active, 
    IFNULL(SUM(s.sold*s.cost), 0) AS earned, 
    checker.movieId IS NOT NULL as work 
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN seance s USING(movieId)
LEFT JOIN seance checker ON
        m.movieId = checker.movieId
    AND checker.active
    AND checker.date >= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY m.movieId
```

Результат:

```
1 foo 1 1190 1
2 bar 1 605  0
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все отлично выводит. Правда я заменил USING на ON.

Comment: подскажите, а если я добавляю новую запись в таблицу `movie` и на данный момент новый фильм не привязан ни к какому сеансу, соответственно его не будет в выборке. Можно ли как то прикрутить запрос такого типа: `SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movieId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT movieId FROM session)` к общему запросу, что бы в выбору добавились фильмы не привязанные к сеансам?

Comment: @OlegDatskevich да, сделать ещё один левый джоин по аналогии